# XSSF Workbook Sorting

Tags: java, xssf

Objective : Sort a selected column alphabetically from A to Z of an existing excel sheet

Is there an inbuilt function for sorting a column A to Z (String type column) in XSSF POI API?
I've tried searching but have not found any useful links.

If not then would I have to write a sorting function to achieve the sorting ? eg bubble sort ?